# Running multiple services on Port 443, Tunnel SSH over HTTPS

Tags: https, lighttpd, ssh-tunnel, firewall

**Situation:**
I want to tunnel SSH sessions through HTTPS. I have a very restrictive firewall/proxy which only allows HTTP, FTP and HTTPS traffic.

**What works:**
Setting up a tunnel through the proxy to a remote linux box that has a sshd listening at port 443

**The problem:**
I have to have a web server (lighty) running at port 443. HTTPS traffic to other ports is forbidden by the proxy.

**Ideas so far:**
Set up a virtual host and proxy all incoming requests to localhost: (e.g. 22)

```
$HTTP["host"] == "tunnel.mylinux.box" {                                         
    proxy.server = (                                                            
        "" => (("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 22))                           
    )                                                                           
}
```

Unfortunately this won't work. Am i doing something wrong, or is there a reason, that this won't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the trick using some Perl:

[sslh - Switch incoming connection between SSH and SSL/HTTPS servers](http://search.cpan.org/~book/Net-Proxy-0.12/script/sslh)

Comment: nice. i'll try that one!

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into the [C implementation of sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml).

From the website:

> sslh lets one accept both HTTPS and SSH connections on the same port. It makes it possible to connect to an SSH server on port 443 (e.g. from inside a corporate firewall) while still serving HTTPS on that port. This feature has already been implemented as a Perl script.
>
> There are two problems with sslh:
>    - It's in Perl. That means it's pretty RAM hungry, and probably not very fast.
>    - It doesn't manage privilege dropping, which is rather questionnable.
>
> The obvious solution to both problems was to re-implement it in C, which is what this program is about.